# Git checkout branches to their own folders

Tags: git

Some time ago I watched a video on YouTube where a guy explained how you can clone a repo in some kind of a special way and then checkout branches to their own directories in that root repo folder, so that you can work on several branches in parallel without having to stash stuff or make intermediate commits, and just switch to that other directory. Probably even open them in your IDE.

I thought I'd give it a try, but I can't find any documentation on that. All I can find relates to checking out specific directories, and not to what I want.

Can anyone direct me to the right documentation on this?

Comment: The feature you want is called "worktrees". It allows you to have multiple check-out working directories for a single repository: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree

Comment: The video might have been made before `git worktree` existed. There was an old contrib script that used tricky hacks to do what's now built in to Git. *Avoid* the tricky hacks if at all possible! They have a number of bad corner cases. Even Git got some cases wrong in the initial worktree implementation (make sure your Git version is at least 2.15, preferably 2.17 or later).